# How can i make the last OS used the first to boot in dual windows and ubuntu OS bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu 18.10 and windows 10 as dual OS but whenever i restart from one of the OS i will be given an option to choose the operating system to boot or Ubuntu boot automatically after some seconds. I will love to make the last OS used to boot automatically how can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

This will make GRUB remember the last OS that you booted, and will boot to that same OS until you change it at the GRUB menu.

Edit `/etc/default/grub`

Add/change the following lines near the top...

`GRUB_DEFAULT=saved` # change existing line

`GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true` # add this line

Then, in `terminal`...

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`